# JQuery click works after refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

My deepest apologizes. Here is the link of my question for which I really need assistance. the below query, I have already fixed.

Please help me out anyone.

**[Drag and Drop from localstorage HTML5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521007/drag-and-drop-from-localstorage-html5-not-working)**

I prepared the some drag and drop widgets in HTML, CSS, JQuery. 
Drag and drop works fine. I made an icon to show for the dragged widgets once it is dropped in the place required. The icon shows fine once dropped.

I wanted to remove the widget when we click on the close icon. But it doesn't remove the widget. I tried to refresh the page to see whether it works after that. And it is. I'm not sure why JQuery behaves this way.

I tried to look for the solution. I could see many solutions. But nothing fix my problem. Anyone could help?

Below is the code I have used:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
      var dropClass = localStorage.key(i);
      var clonediv = $("." + dropClass.substr(4, dropClass.length - 4)).clone();
      var droppable = $("#droppable");
      droppable.append(clonediv.draggable({
        helper: 'original',
        revert: 'valid',
        containment: "#droppable",
        grid: [30, 30],
        snap: true
      }).resizable({
        containment: "#droppable"
      }));
      clonediv.find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
      console.log(clonediv);
    }
  } else {}

  $(".bat_voltage").draggable({
    revert: true,
    grid: [30, 30]
  });
  $(".left_flight").draggable({
    revert: true,
    grid: [30, 30]
  });
  $(".cnt_flight").draggable({
    revert: true,
    grid: [30, 30]
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dragged = ui.draggable;
      var id = dragged.attr("class").split(' ');
      var droppable = $("#droppable");
      var find = (droppable.find("." + id[0]));
      console.log(find);
      if (find.length != 0) {} else {
        ui.helper.css({
          'top': 0,
          'left': 0,
          'position': 'relative'
        });
        ui.helper.clone().appendTo("#droppable").draggable({
          containment: "#droppable",
          grid: [30, 30],
          snap: true
        }).resizable({
          containment: "#droppable"
        });
        droppable.find("." + id[0]).find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
        localStorage.setItem("drop" + id[0], droppable);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#change").click(function() {
    var bat_value = parseInt($("#bat_level").val());
    if (bat_value > 25) {
      progressValue(bat_value, "Green");
    } else if (bat_value > 15 && bat_value < 25) {
      progressValue(bat_value, "Yellow");
    } else if (bat_value < 15) {
      progressValue(bat_value, "Red");
    }
  });

  $(".boxclose").click(function() {
    alert("remove widget");
    var par = $(this).parent();
    var id = par.attr("class").split(' ');
    var droppable = $("#droppable");
    var removing = droppable.find("." + id[0]);
    removing.remove();
    localStorage.removeItem("drop" + id[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.bat_voltage {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
.left_flight {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cnt_flight {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#droppable {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 10px;
  resize: both;
  border: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#progressbar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
a.boxclose {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #605F61;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 8px 3px;
  display: block;
}
.displaynone {
  display: none !important;
}
.displayblock {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </HEAD>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="bat_voltage floatleft ui-widget-content">
            <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
            <p>Battery Voltage</p>
          </div>

          <div class="left_flight floatleft ui-widget-content">
            <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
            <p>Flight Time Left</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cnt_flight floatleft ui-widget-content">
            <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
            <p>Current Flight Time</p>
            <div class="curFlight"></div>
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
          <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @vijayP: really sorry about that. I have added the code now. Please check

Comment: you can not put two function in same id or class you are putting drag functionality in id #droppable and also you can make click functionality on this id so at a time online first function will call.

Comment: @RaviSukhadia: I nowhere have more than 1 function for the id. I have created only 1 function for the id #droppable which is to accept the elements dropped. I wrote function inside the drop function only to make changes to the dropping element which is acceptable.

Comment: you have error in code

Comment: @Dave: may I know what is the error? could you please help me rectify

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken and your problem is not adequately described. You should expect little help.

Comment: @GiriDharan is my answer correct? If yes, mark it as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLefqd9g/1/)

Here You are using draggable event and you are adding that close button dynamically

**So whenever you want to remove or want to add any function to dynamically added element you have to do something like this.**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .bat_voltage {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    z-index: 1;
  } 

  .ui-widget-content,
  .ui-widget-header#droppable { border: 2px solid #000; }

  .floatleft {
     float: left;
  }
 .left_flight {
   width: 250px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 .cnt_flight {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 #droppable {
   width: 50%;
   height: 400px;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 10px;
   resize: both;
   border: 2px;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 #progressbar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
 }
 a.boxclose {
   float: right;
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-right: -10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
   border-radius: 8px;
   background: #605F61;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 0px;
   padding: 8px 3px;
   display: block;
 }
 .displaynone {
   display: none !important;
 }
 .displayblock {
   display: none !important;
 }
</style>
<script>
  $(function () {
   if (localStorage.length != 0) {
   for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
     var dropClass = localStorage.key(i);
     var clonediv = $("." + dropClass.substr(4, dropClass.length - 4)).clone();
     var droppable = $("#droppable");
     droppable.append(clonediv.draggable({
       helper: 'original',
       revert: 'valid',
       containment: "#droppable",
       grid: [30, 30],
       snap: true
     }).resizable({
       containment: "#droppable"
     }));
     clonediv.find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
     console.log(clonediv);
   }
  } else {}

 $(".bat_voltage").draggable({
   revert: true,
   grid: [30, 30]
 });
 $(".left_flight").draggable({
  revert: true,
  grid: [30, 30]
});
$(".cnt_flight").draggable({
  revert: true,
  grid: [30, 30]
});
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dragged = ui.draggable;
    var id = dragged.attr("class").split(' ');
    var droppable = $("#droppable");
    var find = (droppable.find("." + id[0]));
    console.log(find);
    if (find.length != 0) {} else {
      ui.helper.css({
      'top': 0,
      'left': 0,
      'position': 'relative'
      });
      ui.helper.clone().appendTo("#droppable").draggable({
      containment: "#droppable",
      grid: [30, 30],
      snap: true
      }).resizable({
        containment: "#droppable"
      });
      droppable.find("." + id[0]).find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
      localStorage.setItem("drop" + id[0], droppable);
    }
   }
 });
$("#change").click(function() {
  var bat_value = parseInt($("#bat_level").val());
  if (bat_value > 25) {
    progressValue(bat_value, "Green");
  } else if (bat_value > 15 && bat_value < 25) {
    progressValue(bat_value, "Yellow");
  } else if (bat_value < 15) {
    progressValue(bat_value, "Red");
  }
});

$("body").on('click','.boxclose',function() {
  alert("remove widget");
  var par = $(this).parent();
  var id = par.attr("class").split(' ');
  var droppable = $("#droppable");
  var removing = droppable.find("." + id[0]);
  removing.remove();
  localStorage.removeItem("drop" + id[0]);
 });
});

</script>
</HEAD>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="bat_voltage floatleft ui-widget-content">
        <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
        <p>Battery Voltage</p>
      </div>

      <div class="left_flight floatleft ui-widget-content">
        <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
        <p>Flight Time Left</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cnt_flight floatleft ui-widget-content">
        <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
        <p>Current Flight Time</p>
        <div class="curFlight"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p>Drop here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code missing `});` at end of javascript code.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Fix it and then change `$(".boxclose").click()` to `$(document).on("click", ".boxclose");`

This code works for me

```
<HTML><HEAD>
  <style>
  .bat_voltage { width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; z-index:1; }
  .floatleft { float:left; }
  .left_flight { width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; z-index:1; }
  .cnt_flight { width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; z-index:1; }
  #droppable { width: 50%; height: 400px; padding: 0.5em; margin: 10px; resize:both; border: 2px; overflow:auto; }
  #progressbar { width: 200px; height: 50px; margin-top: 20px; }
  a.boxclose{ float:right; margin-top:-10px; margin-right:-10px; cursor:pointer; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #AEAEAE; border-radius: 8px; background: #605F61; font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; line-height: 0px; padding: 8px 3px; display: block; }
    .displaynone { display:none !important; }
    .displayblock { display:none !important; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function () {
        if (localStorage.length != 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                var dropClass = localStorage.key(i);
                var clonediv = $("." + dropClass.substr(4, dropClass.length - 4)).clone();
                var droppable = $("#droppable");
                droppable.append(clonediv.draggable({ helper: 'original', revert: 'valid', containment: "#droppable", grid: [30, 30], snap: true }).resizable({ containment: "#droppable" }));
                clonediv.find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
                console.log(clonediv);
            }
        }
        else { }

        $(".bat_voltage").draggable({ revert:true, grid: [30,30] });
        $(".left_flight").draggable({ revert:true, grid: [30, 30] });
        $(".cnt_flight").draggable({ revert: true, grid: [30, 30] });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var dragged = ui.draggable;
                var id = dragged.attr("class").split(' ');
                var droppable = $("#droppable");
                var find = (droppable.find("." + id[0]));
                console.log(find);
                if (find.length != 0) { }
                else {
                    ui.helper.css({ 'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'position': 'relative' });
                    ui.helper.clone().appendTo("#droppable").draggable({ containment: "#droppable", grid: [30, 30], snap: true }).resizable({ containment: "#droppable" });
                    droppable.find("." + id[0]).find('a').removeClass("displayblock");
                    localStorage.setItem("drop" + id[0], droppable);
                }
            }
        });
        $("#change").click(function () {
            var bat_value = parseInt($("#bat_level").val());
            if (bat_value > 25) { progressValue(bat_value, "Green"); }
            else if (bat_value > 15 && bat_value < 25) { progressValue(bat_value, "Yellow"); }
            else if (bat_value < 15) { progressValue(bat_value, "Red"); }
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".boxclose", function () {
            alert("remove widget");
            var par = $(this).parent();
            var id = par.attr("class").split(' ');
            var droppable = $("#droppable");
            var removing = droppable.find("." + id[0]);
            removing.remove();
            localStorage.removeItem("drop" + id[0]);
        });
    });
 </script>

 </HEAD>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div>
    <div class="bat_voltage floatleft ui-widget-content" >
         <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
      <p>Battery Voltage</p>
    </div>

    <div class="left_flight floatleft ui-widget-content" >
         <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
      <p>Flight Time Left</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cnt_flight floatleft ui-widget-content" >
         <a class="boxclose displayblock">×</a>
      <p>Current Flight Time</p>
        <div class="curFlight"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
            <p>Drop here</p>
        </div>


</div>
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5tsbtaue/)

Answer (score 0):

The working on refresh issue you are having is usually happening when your code is calling for an element that is not yet on the page when you load the page. By refreshing the page your code is being run again and the element is on the page so it just happen to work.

Make sure that you use the on document load so your code will run only when the page is completely loaded.